# Non time-homogeneous Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a Markov chain over a finite state space $\Omega$, that is non time-homogeneous.

Suppose there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n\geq1$ and all $x,x'\in\Omega$ either $P(X_{n+1}=x'|X_t=x)\geq \epsilon>0$ or $P(X_{n+1}=x'|X_t=x)=0$.

I would like to know how to define recurrent classes in this context.

Comment: Are recurrent classes not defined according to whether you can reach from one state to the other in some finite time? Since you have finite states is it not just the states that are connected by some positive probability?

Comment: What does "connected" mean in this context? You may have a positive probability of going from [$x$ at stage $1$] to $x'$ but a zero probability of going from [$x$ at stage $2$] to $x'$.

Comment: I would assume (that is why I am putting in the comments and not the answer) that if there is a non-zero probability from x to x' infinitely often (lim sup), then they are connected, I would definitely double check though.

Comment: How would you write it mathematically? I guess there should be some bound on the number of stage to go from $x$ to $x'$.

Comment: If you have finite number of states (k) it shouldn't be more than that since if you ever loop back that means you could have just started from there... Hmm I would say that x is connected to x' if for any given n, there is a d < k, $n_0 > n$ s.t. $P(X_{n_0 + d} = x' | X_{n_0} = x) > 0$.

Comment: This is right now just a magical definition; I would probably define it according to what the situation asks for... if I cared about steady state the above is probably how I would define it